# using log4j to write json objects to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

How to write some data into a log file using lo4j with following requirments

1)Write only what i ask to. Dont write which java code line wrote to that file?
All the file should contain is some data

For example i will write something like

```
String s = obj.toJson();
logger.info(s);
```

The above like should only write s to file.

I should be able to read Object obj back from this files.

Also many objects will be written to this file.Also i need to use other features of log4j like creating a new file every hour.

Comment: Read through log4j's documentation: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @Marcelo I tried it but not understanding , so asked here.I dont think this question deserves a  downvote

Comment: I will try to lead you in the right direction. If you only want to write the json objects to a file, why are you using log4j instead of for example a `FileWriter` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the loggers format and/or create a new formatter. 
Just google something like "log4j formatter" and you will find something like http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html.
There are plenty of options, display time, display method, etc.

Edit:
read! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm

And i would not suggest to use a logger to print jsons into a file (if not error / debug)